# sed replace range of lines with a single word

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I tried my best to get this and had little luck, I have following file  and I want to replace 
first `“<Connector port="8080"” xml block with ‘xxxx’`

Before :

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

After :

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
xxxx
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

I  got the matching string  to print using following sed command :

```
sed -n '/<Connector port="8080"/,/>/p' filename
```

However I’m unable to develop this to get above output.

Comment: Be aware that replacing an element in XML with regular expressions (i.e. `sed`) is not possible for all general XML documents. With `sed`, you can only solve this problem in a subset of XML documents. For general XML processing, use a proper XML processing technology such as XSLT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1841533

Comment: @ndim: True. However, in this case it is not general xml, it is a very specific case, which does in deed work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` should do the trick on your sample input (but gets overzealous if you have more than one `<Connector port="8080"` section):

```
sed '/<Connector port="8080"/,/>/{ s/<Connector.*/xxxx/; t; d  }'
```

But handling this robustly calls for an XML parser.  Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML
d = Document.new(File.read(ARGV[0]))
e = d.get_elements('//Connector[@port="8080"]').first
if !e.nil?
    e.parent.insert_after(e, Text.new('xxxx'))
    e.parent.delete(e)
end
File.open(ARGV[0],'w'){|f| f.print(d) }
```

Comment: Be aware the difference between _parsing_ and _searching_ xml. I'm all for not trying to parse xml using regex, but in this case it is not actually parsing that is asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  '/<Connector port="8080"/,/>/ {
   N
   />/ s/.*/xxxx/
  }' YourFile
```

load the section of connector before changing it to xxxx, this allow you to eventually test something on it (but not better than pobrelkey if not)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers , they worked well .Appriciate it:
Also i got following from one of my firend which also a answer to this using awk

```
awk '/<Connector port/ {
print "abc"
getline
do {
 getline
} while (index($0, ">") == 0)
getline
} 
// { print $0}' < 1.txt
```